# unable to install catkin on noetic, ubuntu 20.04 with kubuntu

Tags: catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Suposing that catkin was automatically installed with noetic, when I used `catkin_make`, the command was not found. I tried to install catkin but I received :

```
The following packages have unset dependencies:
    catkin: Depends: python3-catkin-pkg (>= 0.4.14-2)but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

The package `python3-catkin-pkg` (0.4.24-100) is really installed.

What can I do?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/394849/unable-to-install-catkin-on-noetic,-ubuntu-20.04-with-kubuntu/) by [MiguelMTS](https://answers.ros.org/users/94563/miguelmts/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2022-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-24**:
Pls make sure not to forget to source.

Also check prior answers: https://answers.ros.org/question/341758/catkin_make-python-catkin-pkg-doesnt-work/

**Comment by [MiguelMTS](https://answers.ros.org/users/94563/miguelmts/) on 2022-01-24**:
I did not forget to source.
I also had used the same repositories as in question 3417.and that was the result.

**Comment by [AlessioParmeggiani](https://answers.ros.org/users/94489/alessioparmeggiani/) on 2022-01-25**:
Have you tried installing python catkin tools?

```
sudo apt install python3-catkin-tools
```

**Comment by [MiguelMTS](https://answers.ros.org/users/94563/miguelmts/) on 2022-01-25**:
Yes, I did too, and finally arrived to the impossibility aforementioned.

I have repeated the process from the beginning several times and in different ways and always gat the same final result.

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2022-01-25**:
It could be a Kubuntu issue not necessarily ROS. Ubuntu is the recommended OS

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-25**:
What is the output of:

1. `lsb_release -a`
2. `dpkg -l | grep catkin`
3. after `source`ing: `which catkin_make`

And what does:

> I did not forget to source

mean *exactly*?

Unless you've setup to auto-`source` (via your `.bashrc` fi), you'll have to `source` in *every* terminal manually. A single time won't work for future terminals.

---

Edit, just noticed:

> I tried to install catkin [..]

*how*? Which command did you use, exactly?

Note that `catkin` is not the same package as `python3-catkin-pkg`.

And the latter is not the package which provides the `catkin_make` command. That would be `ros-noetic-catkin`. Are you perhaps mixing in [wiki/UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages)?

**Comment by [MiguelMTS](https://answers.ros.org/users/94563/miguelmts/) on 2022-01-25**:
Yes, I included source via .bashrc.
I  used ros-noetic-catkin

The result for dpkg is:

```
      ii              python3-catkin               0.8.0-1ubuntu2                 all
      ii              python3-catkin-pkg        0.4.16-1                            all
```

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-26**:
please answer all questions, and be precise.

We cannot help you otherwise.

**Comment by [MiguelMTS](https://answers.ros.org/users/94563/miguelmts/) on 2022-01-26**:
Sorry.
1.-Before installing noetic

From lsb_release -a, I receive:

```
NoLSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Release:         20.04
Codename:     focal
```

**But now the situation has changed**

I am installing on RaspberryPi 4.

Ubuntu 20.04.3 Server LTS (desktop versión is not available)
With the apt update after the curl command, there appears an error when getting

```
http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu foval InRelease
   The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available:   NO_PUBKEY F42ED6FBAB17C654
```

Then I tried with `gpg --fetch-keys https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ros/rosdistro/master/ros.asc`
That imported the key for `'Open Robotics <info@osrfoundation.org>"`
But again Received the same error after apt update.:

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-01-26**:\

> I am installing on RaspberryPi 4

this is the first time you mention this.

In the future, please provide pertinent details like this, as otherwise it will be very difficult for people here to help you.

> there appears an error when getting `http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu foval InRelease`

is `foval` a typo? Or did you copy-paste it?

The correct codename for your distribution would be `focal` (note: `c`, not `v`).

**Comment by [MiguelMTS](https://answers.ros.org/users/94563/miguelmts/) on 2022-01-26**:
Sorry. It was a typo error in the comment. Of course the message says focal, not foval.
And sorry again, I missed to mention the Raspberry in my first entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thank you all for your help.
Finally I got everything installed correctly.
Bu I don't know yet where was the failure.
For sure, as  I had included the source into the .bashrc file as a first step, in my first reboot it didn't recognized the path of the source because ths noetic directory did not exist yet. From so on, that source was not registered.
Thank you very much indeed and I apologize the time you have dedicated.

---

Originally posted by [MiguelMTS](https://answers.ros.org/users/94563/miguelmts/) with karma: 16 on 2022-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0